# How do i query xata data base using vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, xata

```
  ` methods: {
    async getData() {
    const xata = getXataClient();
    const page = await xata.db.quiz
   .select(["questions", "answer", "options", "selected"])
   .getPaginated({
    pagination: {
    size: 15,
      },
    });
    console.log(page.records);
    },
    },`
```

I'm new to Xata data base, and i've created a data base but i can't  query xata using vue js

Comment: The call to the Xata API look ok, do you get an error? If yes, can you post it here, please?

Answer (score 1):

You actually can’t query Xata from vue since it’s a frontend framework (more information on why you shouldn’t do this here -> https://xata.io/blog/securely-querying-your-database-on-xata)

If you want help, I invite you to join [xata’s discord channel](https://xata.io/discord)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Follow up on Fabien0102's comment

> You actually can’t query Xata from vue since it’s a frontend framework (more > information on why you shouldn’t do this here ->
> https://xata.io/blog/securely-querying-your-database-on-xata)

I would recommend looking into Nuxt 3 which is out of beta and has ha very pleasent developer experience.

What you need [to solve your issue is the `server`-folder](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-directory)(located in root) and either a JS or TS file with eg.:

- server

  - api

    - quiz.js
    - logout.js

Then in your one of your ts files:

```js
// filepath: server/api/quiz.js
export default defineEventHandler(async () => {

  const xata = getXataClient();
  const page = await xata.db.quiz
   .select(["questions", "answer", "options", "selected"])
   .getPaginated({
      pagination: {
      size: 15,
    },
  });
  return page
})
```

It will then be available on http://localhost:3000/api/quiz. Then fetch it in your vue file as you would. ([I also recommend testing useAsyncData since your now in a nuxt enviroment](https://nuxt.com/docs/examples/composables/use-async-data))